# Getting "resolve-url-loader: CSS error" on PC, when I run the same code on Mac & PC

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to run the same project using
`npm install` then
`npm start` on both my Macbook Pro and Windows Desktop. The issue I am facing is that on my Desktop I am getting the error:

`Error: resolve-url-loader: CSS error source-map information is not available at url() declaration (found orphan CR, try removeCR option)`

Whenever `npm start` is finished firing. On my Mac it loads the web app just fine.

**Q: Is there something (i.e. a setting) that I am missing here / that I need to ensure is altered properly based on which type of machine I am running this on, or does this sound like an issue with my code somewhere?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

In my case you probably have to change a Boolean in the index.js of the module `resolve-url-loader`.

Just change `removeCR : false` to `removeCR : true` and try to start again.

Happy coding :)